# Error in installation of Adobe Acrobat Reader - "The package is of bad quality"

Tags: adobe

To install Adobe Acrobat Reader in my Ubuntu 13.04 amd64bit I downloaded the .deb installation file from the Adobe-Website and opened the file using the Software center (as suggested while downloading).

The installation failed, with the Software Center warning me that "The package is of bad quality" and giving me a long list of details starting with this

```
Lintian check results for /tmp/AdbeRdr9.4.2-1_i386linux_deu.deb:

E: adobereader-deu: control-file-has-bad-permissions postinst 0555 != 0755

E: adobereader-deu: control-file-has-bad-owner postinst acrorel/named != root/root

E: adobereader-deu: control-file-has-bad-permissions prerm 0555 != 0755

E: adobereader-deu: control-file-has-bad-owner prerm acrorel/named != root/root

E: adobereader-deu: maintainer-address-missing Adobe Systems, Incorporated

E: adobereader-deu: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid etc/ 10490/25

E: adobereader-deu: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid etc/bash_completion.d/ 10490/25

E: adobereader-deu: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid etc/bash_completion.d/acroread.sh 10490/25

E: adobereader-deu: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid opt/ 10490/25

E: adobereader-deu: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid opt/Adobe/ 10490/25

E: adobereader-deu: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid opt/Adobe/Reader9/ 10490/25

E: adobereader-deu: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid opt/Adobe/Reader9/Browser/ 10490/25

...going on with a list of details all starting with:

E: adobereader-deu: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid opt/Adobe/Reader9/
```

Now I don't know whether I can install it anyway, ignoring the warning, or how the problem can be solved. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: For most people, Adobe Reader is a bloated, slow pile of junk. Is there any *specific* reason that you need its extra features over the open source integrated pdf reader?

Comment: Actually I didn't realize, there are open source pdf reader - What are their names? What I basically need is the ability to comment in a pdf document. Do the open source readers have that?

Comment: If you're committed to installing Adobe Reader, use `dpkg` instead. `cd /location_of_deb_pkg` then `sudo dpkg -i name_of_deb_pkg`

Comment: Ok, where do I have to type all this into? The Terminal? I'm still a total newbie..

Answer (score 2):

If you don't actually need Adobe Reader, use Evince, which is included in Ubuntu.
Since the author of this question only needs annotation, Evince can do that, but the option is hidden. [Here](http://blogs.perl.org/users/cyocum/2011/10/annotating-pdfs-with-evince.html)'s how to annotate PDFs in Evince.

If you actually have a reason to *need* Adobe Reader, ignore how they sloppily made their package, and install it anyway.